# ActiveRecord to_json specifying options for included methods

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've got the following to_json in my view:
`<%=raw @forums.to_json(:methods => [:topic_count, :last_post]) %>;`

and in the model I've got the following method:

```
def last_post
    post = ForumPost.joins(:forum_topic).where(:forum_topics => {:forum_id => self.id}).order("forum_posts.created_at DESC").first
    return post
end
```

However ForumPost contains a relation to a ForumTopic (`belongs_to :forum_topic`) and I want to include this ForumTopic in my json so I end up with {..., "last_post":{..., "forum_topic":{...}...}, ...}. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's better to keep that kind of declaration in the Model.  You can override the as_json method in your models.  This approach allows you to control the the serialization behavior for your entire object graph, and you can write unit tests for this stuff.

In this example I'm guessing that your @forums variable refers to a model called Forum, if i'm wrong hopefully you still get the idea.

```
class Forum
    ...
    def as_json(options={})
        super(methods: [:topic_count, :last_post])
    end
end
class ForumPost
    ...
    def as_json(options={})
        super(methods: [:forum_topic])
    end
end
```

Comment: Reason I wanted to keep it out of the model is because not every time I use to_json do I want to include all this data. In this example I'm specifically including so much data because the json printed is being used to bootstrap a backbone collection. ForumPost and Forum are converted to json elsewhere apart from this view and I don't really want them to include this data every time.

Comment: You might want to look at jose valim's active model serializers https://github.com/josevalim/active_model_serializers I've not used it yet, but it looks like the right approach for managing different kinds of serilization for different purposes.  Creating these crazy hashes of options for to_json or as_json is really really horrible, and this seems to be a good approach.